# incompatible types: int cannot be converted to java.awt.Color

Tags: java

I'm pretty new in java and I was attempting to debug this little project but I cannot figure out what the issue with the last line is.

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

/**
 * Basic debugging exercise - There are 4 errors in this program.  Find them,
 * correct them, and compile the program to verify that your program matches
 */
public class DebugMe extends JFrame
{
    int x;

    private String message = "Congratulations, the program is working again.";
    Image debug = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("debug.jpeg")).getImage();
    /**
     * Constructor for objects of class DebugMe
     */
    public DebugMe()
    {
        x = 0;//x was not initialized
        setSize(500, 500);
        setVisible(true);//syntax error there was capital T
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        DebugMe myDebugMe = new DebugMe();//syntax error there was a lower case M
        int x;
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g)
    {
        super.paint(g);
        g.drawString("message", 100, 100);
        g.drawImage(debug, 100, 200, 200, 200);
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you look at the docs of `drawImage()`: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html

Comment: I went and reviewed the link but how would I know which is the best option in this case?

Comment: You try to figure out what you have and what the required parameters are in this case since you have 4 ints the closest one is drawImage(Image img, int x, int y, int width, int height, ImageObserver observer)

Answer (score 1):

It's looking for an ImageObserver which happens to be an interface implemented by JFrame.  So you can just use:

```
g.drawImage(debug, 100, 200, 200, 200, this);
```

Comment: Thanks Charles that did clear the error, now I'm receiving a runtime error I will look into this and see if I can figure it out.